# Html email font outline

Tags: css, html-email

I'm trying to achieve a black, 1 pixel outline around a header written with white fonts, but I've just realised that gmail doesn't support this:

```
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;  
}
```

How can I resolve this with something supported?

Comment: Are you able to use svg? There's a [guide on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/) devoted to this topic with browser support

Comment: @chazsolo not really

Comment: Email clients have really bad CSS support, so don't count too much on them for rendering text shadows. Depending on the need, you might have to generated a static image, or embed an image linked to a dynamic generator, or simply choose to make do without the stroke effect.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get without text shadow is the poorly supported text-stroke property:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px  black;
```

http://codepen.io/c0un7z3r0/pen/VKQmaz

I couldnt even get this working in firefox but chrome is fine. I'd consider using a image in this situation. Not ideal but I beleieve email html has more stringent controls (specifically white text being a big no-no).

http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke

SOURCE: https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Comment: Remember that OP is talking about HTML emails. Email clients are notorious for poor support for modern CSS specifications. An image is likely to be more relevant than a styled text for the effect desired.